# Thread sleep is inconsistance in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I found a surprising things about Thread.sleep. Thread doesn't wake up in time. Let me explain. I create an activity (no service) and run a thread like the following.

```
Thread.sleep(50000); // 50 seconds
System.out.println("something");
```

Then i keep the activity in foreground and off the display (by pressing power button). Also i was logging in a file saved in sdcard. What i found that, After almost 10 min Thread delay 7.35 minutes to print instead of 50 seconds. Is it normal?? Can i trust on Thread.sleep()?

```
16:47:57 ---- START
-------- 
-------- (all are in time)
--------
16:57:07 -- (in time)
16:57:57 -- (in time)
17:05:38 --- (late)
```

Comment: Where in your activity's code are you calling sleep?

Comment: @Zymurgeek It's complicated. But you can assume that a simple thread is running in onCreate(). Also there are 3 waiting thread running in parallel. But they are independent.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i trust on Thread.sleep()?

You can trust it to behave as specified<sup>1</sup>.  But the specification says that a sleep will cause the thread to stop for *at least* that number of milliseconds.  Under some circumstances, it could stop for longer.  For example, if there is a lot of work for a higher priority thread to do, a lower priority thread may not be woken from the sleep for a long time.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, in theory, it *might not* behave as specified.  But you've tendered no evidence to support that ...</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to make an accurate time of `sleep` of a thread in Java ?

Comment: Not unless you use real-time Java on a real-time OS platform.

Comment: Sleep is the wrong choice here.  If you want accuracy, use a timer.

Comment: Is there any situation that android device go to sleep after a certain period? Because it is happening in android device. I don't need actually higher time efficiency. Less than 1 second of extra delay is bearable.

Comment: Try using `Timer`.  But I suspect that if `Thread.sleep` is giving large unexplained pauses then `Timer` will too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
LockSupport.parkNanos(nanos)
```

Or other methods it provides. It's more accurate.

Comment: I just created a small test case where I executed Thread.sleep(1) in a loop and used System.nanoTime in order to check how much time actually passed in that call to Thread.sleep. This varied from a bit over 1ms or a bit over 5ms. Unfortunately replacing Thread.sleep with LockSupport.parkNanos yielded the same results. So for me LockSupport.parkNanos seems just as inaccurate as Thread.sleep. Is there any documentation telling that LockSupport.parkNanos is better in terms of accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that when you turn off the screen using power button then android go to sleep after sometimes. CPU also go to sleep when screen is off. That's whey Thread.sleep() is giving large delay. In my case my device was in sleep mode for `7.30` minute and when i turn on the screen `cpu` wake up and start the Thread again. By acquiring the Partial_wake_lock you can hold `cpu` to go to sleep even when you press the power button(not shutdown).

[More details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)